# How do you get to a DD-WRT router's configuration page? (repeater bridge)

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, wifi-configuration

Here is my internet setup:

> Internet → Apartment WiFi → DD-WRT Router

The router has been configured as a repeater bridge per the guide in the DD-WRT wiki: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge

Now I can access the internet by connecting to my DD-WRT router. However, when I try and navigate to my router config by putting in the router's IP, the request times out.

`ipconfig` says the default gateway is `10.245.220.1`. This address sends me the Apartment WiFi page.

'tracert' shows that a request for the router's default IP (`192.168.1.1`) is passed through to the Apartment WiFi:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    26 ms     5 ms     4 ms  logout.lan [10.245.220.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *     ^C
```

The behavior is identical whether accessing the DD-WRT router via cable or wireless.

How do I access my router's configuration page?

Comment: *Note to holier-than-thou types: The lease agreement says I can.*

Comment: so, it looks like you get your ip configuration from your Appartment wifi... can you turn off this DHCP, and use the DHCP from DD-WRT? (maybe you have to change the wifi from router to hotspot mode)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to give your computer a static IP address on the same range as the DD-WRT router to be able to access it.

This can be done on either the ethernet or WiFi interface. Once the static IP address has been set to an IP address in the same range ( should start with `192.168.1.2` and end with `192.168.1.254` ), you'll be able to point your computer to `192.168.1.1` and access the DD-WRT configuration page.

Answer (score 4):

The page you reference above, http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge, suggests setting up a static IP address for the RB (=Repeater Birdge). It states:

> Open the Setup -> Basic Setup tab
>
> Connection Type will be: Disabled
>
> Set STP for Disabled (Enabled sometimes can cause connection problems)
>
> IP Address : 192.168.1.2 (Assuming Primary Router IP is 192.168.1.1)
>
> Mask : 255.255.255.0
>
> Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (again assuming Primary Router IP is 192.168.1.1)
>
> DHCP Server: Disable
>
> Local DNS: 192.168.1.1 (if IP of Primary Router is 192.168.1.1)
>
> Assign WAN Port to Switch : Optionally enable this to use the WAN port as another LAN port.
>
> Save

If you have done this, then the configuration page of your RB will be accessible at the IP address (to be typed in your browser) 192.168.1.2.

If you have **not** done this, then most likely your RB will have been given an IP address by your DHCP server, 192.168.1.1. To identify it, I  suggest you use `nmap`, a precious utility which exists for all OSes. Then you can run a `ping scan` (in Linux and Unix you can do it as follows

```
  sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

and there must be an equivalent command also for Windows, should you be on Windows), which will list all pcs which have joined your LAN. Your RB might identify itself easily, or, if you are unlucky, you may have to check the MAC address to see which one corresponds to the producer of your RB. At worst, you can just try to connect, through your browser to all IP addresses returned by `nmap`.